# What's the intersection point of two lines given in canonical form?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I hope someone can help me with this:

What's the intersection point of two lines given in canonical form?

$ D1 : \frac{x}{2} = \frac{y}{-3} = \frac{z}{1} $

$ D2 : \frac{x+1}{3} = \frac{y+5}{2} = \frac{z}{1} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your System in the form
$$x=2t$$
$$y=-3t$$
$$z=t$$
and
$$x=3s-1$$
$$y=2s-5$$
$$z=s$$
from the last equation we get
$$t=s$$ so we get
$$s=t=1$$ and we get the searched Point
as
$$P(2;-3;1)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x}{2} = \frac{x+1}{3} \rightarrow x = 2, \frac{y}{-3} = \frac{y+5}{2} \rightarrow y = -3, z = 1$. Thus, such point is $(2, -3, 1)$

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the lines you give have an intersection point, all you have to do is: from D1 you get: 3x + 2y = 0. From D2 you get: 2x - 3y = 13. Find x,y by solving the system  and then take for example the equation x/2 = z(of line D1) to find z by replacing x from the solution.(you should get the same z from D2,too).